# Парсинг сайта python3

Tags: python, парсер

Я решил написать парсер для отзывов, но когда отзывов нет, то значение переменой `None`:

````
url = f'https://po-nomeru.ru/phone/{phonenun}/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
feedback = soup.find('blockquote')

if feedback == "None":
    print("Feedbacks none")
else:
    await msg.answer(f"<b> Отзывы:</b>\n<code>{feedback}</code>") ```
````

Как сделать, чтобы при значении `None` текст не выводился?

Comment: Попробуй замени `if feedback == "None":` на `if not feedback:`

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: `None` и `"None"` это так-то разные вещи, если что

Comment: спасибо, не зналл